# вставка неповторяющихся значений в mssql python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sql-server

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Использовал sqllite3 там можно было сделать так

```
cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE into register values (?,?,?)", (name,time_visit,date_register_visit))
```

при этом поле `date_register_visit` уникальное.
Хочу теперь сделать тоже самое для mssql. Но не нашел как это можно сделать.
Разобрался как просто вставить данные

```
cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE into register values (?,?,?)", (name,time_visit,date_register_visit))
```

Суть проблемы в том что я использую sheduler. И каждый раз когда вызываб функцию для вставки значений в бд получаю старые + новые записи.Как надо изменить запрос чтобы данные не дублировались в mssql?
Про insert or ignore в mssql ничего не нашел.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220753/what-is-a-insert-ignore-equivalent-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: @MaxU `insert into register(name,time_visit,date_register_visit)
    select date_register_visit
    from register
    where not exists (select 1 from register where oldtable.id = newtable.id)`
если я правильно понял запрос, только вот вопрос что в моем случае писать место  `oldtable.id = newtable.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
sql = """
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM register WHERE name = ? and time_visit = ? 
 and date_register_visit = ?)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO register values (?,?,?);
END;
"""
params = (name, time_visit, date_register_visit) * 2
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: сработало при изменении строки `cursor.execute(sql, params=params)` на `cursor.execute(sql, params)`